# What is wrong with my last if statement that checks for a draw in tic tac toe? Can I use a loop?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to check if there is a draw in the tic tac toe game. This is a user vs user tic tac toe game, it identifies the winner correctly. I am having problems with my last if statement where I attempt to check for any draws. Can I get any guidence in creating a loop or if statement that checks if there is no winner then it is a draw. Please Help. Thanks.

Public Class Form1

```
Dim choice As Boolean
Dim playerXwins, playerOwins As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Panel1.Enabled = False
    Button1.Enabled = False
    Button2.Enabled = False
    Button3.Enabled = False
    Button4.Enabled = False
    Button5.Enabled = False
    Button6.Enabled = False
    Button7.Enabled = False
    Button8.Enabled = False
    Button9.Enabled = False
    ExitButton.Enabled = False

End Sub

Private Sub ExitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitButton.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub


Private Sub PlayButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PlayButton.Click

    PlayButton.Enabled = False
    Panel1.Enabled = True
    Button1.Enabled = True
    Button2.Enabled = True
    Button3.Enabled = True
    Button4.Enabled = True
    Button5.Enabled = True
    Button6.Enabled = True
    Button7.Enabled = True
    Button8.Enabled = True
    Button9.Enabled = True
    ExitButton.Enabled = True


End Sub

Private Sub Buttons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click, Button5.Click, Button6.Click, Button7.Click, Button8.Click, Button9.Click

    If choice = False Then
        CType(sender, Button).Text = "X"
        choice = True
    Else
        CType(sender, Button).Text = "O"
        choice = False
    End If
    ChoosingWinner()

End Sub

Private Sub ChoosingWinner()

    If Button1.Text = "X" And Button2.Text = "X" And Button3.Text = "X" Then
        MsgBox("Player X Won this Round")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerXwins = playerXwins + 1
        Label2.Text = playerXwins


    ElseIf Button1.Text = "X" And Button4.Text = "X" And Button7.Text = "X" Then
        MsgBox("Player X Won Round")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerXwins = playerXwins + 1
        Label2.Text = playerXwins

    ElseIf Button1.Text = "X" And Button5.Text = "X" And Button9.Text = "X" Then
        MsgBox("Player X Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerXwins = playerXwins + 1
        Label2.Text = playerXwins
    End If

    If Button2.Text = "X" And Button5.Text = "X" And Button8.Text = "X" Then
        MsgBox("Player X Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerXwins = playerXwins + 1
        Label2.Text = playerXwins
    End If

    If Button3.Text = "X" And Button6.Text = "X" And Button9.Text = "X" Then
        MsgBox("Player X Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerXwins = playerXwins + 1
        Label2.Text = playerXwins
    End If

    If Button3.Text = "X" And Button5.Text = "X" And Button7.Text = "X" Then
        MsgBox("Player X Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerXwins = playerXwins + 1
        Label2.Text = playerXwins
    End If

    If Button4.Text = "X" And Button5.Text = "X" And Button6.Text = "X" Then
        MsgBox("Player X Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerXwins = playerXwins + 1
        Label2.Text = playerXwins
    End If

    If Button7.Text = "X" And Button8.Text = "X" And Button9.Text = "X" Then
        MsgBox("Player X Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerXwins = playerXwins + 1
        Label2.Text = playerXwins
    End If

    If Button1.Text = "O" And Button2.Text = "O" And Button3.Text = "O" Then
        MsgBox("Player O Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerOwins = playerOwins + 1
        Label1.Text = playerOwins
    End If

    If Button1.Text = "O" And Button4.Text = "O" And Button7.Text = "O" Then
        MsgBox("Player O Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerOwins = playerOwins + 1
        Label1.Text = playerOwins
    End If

    If Button1.Text = "O" And Button5.Text = "O" And Button9.Text = "O" Then
        MsgBox("Player O Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerOwins = playerOwins + 1
        Label1.Text = playerOwins
    End If

    If Button2.Text = "O" And Button5.Text = "O" And Button8.Text = "O" Then
        MsgBox("Player O Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerOwins = playerOwins + 1
        Label1.Text = playerOwins
    End If


    If Button3.Text = "O" And Button6.Text = "O" And Button9.Text = "O" Then
        MsgBox("Player O Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerOwins = playerOwins + 1
        Label1.Text = playerOwins
    End If

    If Button3.Text = "O" And Button5.Text = "O" And Button7.Text = "O" Then
        MsgBox("Player O Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerOwins = playerOwins + 1
        Label1.Text = playerOwins
    End If

    If Button4.Text = "O" And Button5.Text = "O" And Button6.Text = "O" Then
        MsgBox("Player O Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerOwins = playerOwins + 1
        Label1.Text = playerOwins
    End If


    If Button7.Text = "O" And Button8.Text = "O" And Button9.Text = "O" Then
        MsgBox("Player O Won!")
        Button1.Enabled = False
        Button2.Enabled = False
        Button3.Enabled = False
        Button4.Enabled = False
        Button5.Enabled = False
        Button6.Enabled = False
        Button7.Enabled = False
        Button8.Enabled = False
        Button9.Enabled = False
        playerOwins = playerOwins + 1
        Label1.Text = playerOwins

    End If

    'checking if there is a draw?
    If Button1.Text And Button2.Text And Button3.Text And Button4.Text And Button5.Text And Button6.Text And Button7.Text And Button8.Text And Button9.Text = "X" Or "O" Then
        MsgBox("There is a Draw")
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Did you debug your code to find what the issue is, or are you "saving" that for us?

Comment: Yes I did debug it and as soon as I press the button "play" it enables the buttons that will be clicked for the game. But when I added that last if statement it doesnt even let the user press any buttons.

Comment: This was the warning that Im getting:An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "X" to type 'Long' is not valid.

Comment: Debugging is much more than pressing a button - it is an activity.  If/when you get an error, you must tell us the error and the line in the post. Make it easy to help you rather than guessing what the problem is.

Comment: Before I added the last if statement the whole program runs smooth. I figured if the ALL the buttons were equal to some "X" or "Y"  after all button are pressed then it will determine that it  was a draw. But it didnt work out.

Comment: You very seriously need to study [ask] and take the [tour].  Not only does more than half your posts have a negative score - which will have consequences, but also you should take the time to acknowledge the help you have gotten.  `If Button1.Text And...` is not a complete expression.  It will not even compile under `Option Strict`

Comment: Each statement that you put between the `If` and the `And` must evaluate to True/False. Obviously `Button1.Text` does not evaluate to True/False. As you did in the previous If statements, `If Button1.Text = "X" Or Button1.Text = "O" And`

Comment: @Mary Thanks for explaining, it really helps me out alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work. It's not how the vb.net syntax work. Each statement must return true or false.

```
If Button1.Text And Button2.Text And Button3.Text And Button4.Text And Button5.Text And Button6.Text And Button7.Text And Button8.Text And Button9.Text = "X" Or "O" Then
    MsgBox("There is a Draw")
End If
```

You would have to do

```
If (Button1.Text = "O" Or Button1.Text = "X") And
   (Button2.Text = "O" Or Button2.Text = "X") And
   (Button3.Text = "O" Or Button3.Text = "X") And
   (Button4.Text = "O" Or Button4.Text = "X") And
   (Button5.Text = "O" Or Button5.Text = "X") And
   (Button6.Text = "O" Or Button6.Text = "X") And
   (Button7.Text = "O" Or Button7.Text = "X") And
   (Button8.Text = "O" Or Button8.Text = "X") And
   (Button9.Text = "O" Or Button9.Text = "X")
    MsgBox("There is a Draw")
End If
```